# CSS won't load in Gulp production build

Tags: css, gulp

I'm using the [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) library. In development, everything, including my CSS, works perfectly. When I do a production build, most of the CSS isn't being loaded.

The symptom of the problem is pretty simple. After I do a `gulp build`, my single CSS file looks like this:

```
@import url(assets/css/application/dashboard.index.css);
@import url(assets/css/application/detail.alerts.css);
@import url(assets/css/application/detail.index.css);
@import url(assets/css/application/detail.map.css);
@import url(assets/css/application/detail.pod.css);
```

This goes on for a while. (I had to drop in a bunch of CSS files created by a separate development team.)

The same exact thing happens in development mode, but in development the imported files are found and in production they're not. (Production is Heroku, FWIW.)

The main thing I can't understand is why the heck the CSS files *are* found in development. This is what a `tree` of `.tmp` looks like:

```
.tmp
├── partials
│   └── templateCacheHtml.js
└── serve
    ├── 404.html
    ├── app
    │   ├── index.css
    │   ├── index.js
    │   ├── vendor.css
    │   └── views
    │       ├── shipments
    │       │   └── index.html
    │       └── user-sessions
    │           └── new.html
    └── index.html

6 directories, 8 files
```

There's obviously no `assets/css/...` in `.tmp`. The only place, for example, `dashboard.index.css` exists is in `assets/css`, which lives in `src/app/` as opposed to `public` or anything like that.

I'm pretty stumped. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing all `css` to `scss` and that fixed the problem.